# How to interrupt a deftest as soon as one test fails?

Tags: testing, clojure, shortcut

I'm using *clojure.test* and in some tests it makes sense to first verify that some condition hold true.

Is there a way to interrupt a `deftest` as soon as one `"is"` fails?

Minimal case reproducing my problem:

```
REPL> ((deftest example (is false) (is false)))

FAIL in (example) (form-init7701070357449256898.clj:1)
expected: false
  actual: false

FAIL in (example) (form-init7701070357449256898.clj:1)
expected: false
  actual: false
```

I'd like to only have one `"FAIL"` reported instead of two.

Note that I have some tests where I do generate (pseudo-)random data and I then want to call `"is"` several times, from a loop. If I'm doing this, say, 10 000 times then my terminal goes nuts printing all the fails or Emacs gets stuck.

Comment: Why not have something like `(is (not-any? false? (list-of-test-results))`?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in your namespace called **`test-ns-hook`** that gives you full control over what tests are called and when. You can provide a function that does the tests sequentially and stops when one of them fails.
The function will need to be declared in each namespace rather than included in a `use` or `require`